# Calculating LCD display horizontal and vertical porch values

Tags: lcd, display

How should I set the porch and sync values given an LCD display?

For example, say my FHD (1920x1080) display datasheet says its has a total vertical cycle of 1125. I have 45 clocks remaining (subtract 1080 clocks of visible period). Can I rather randomly set the front porch, back porch and the sync to 20, 20, and 5 respectively?

Comment: No, not randomly, but according to the datasheet. Preferably according to some standard which defines the pixel clock, hsync rate and vsync rate. Is this a normal display with some common interface like HDMI input or just a panel with LVDS input?

Comment: Ever since computerised monitors were introduced the proportions on the sync timing has not been particularly critical, but personally I'd go with 2 for each overscan and 41 for the blanking interval if forced to guess...

Comment: @Justme This is a (dual) LVDS panel. The datasheet for the panel doesn't seem to reveal anything specific to the length of sync. Hence my question =(.

Comment: @Jasen Thanks. I will give those values a shot. Does overscan refer to the porches...?

Comment: @AdamLee since it is an LVDS panel it might only look at DE and ignore HS and VS. You need to make sure it uses DE only and you can ignore HS/VS timings.

Comment: @Justme thanks - Wasn't aware these values could be ignored! I will check on the panel datasheet again.